# Line break when exporting tex from lyx

Tags: lyx

When I export my lyx file into *.tex it always create hard line break no matter how I do I adjust the word wrapping settings. I'm wondering whether anyone has the same problem and knows how to solve it. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why is that a problem? Does it affect PDF output? Often when you ask a question it is useful if you mention why something is a problem. It is OK to say something like "I just like it like this" (sometimes I have questions like that) but otherwise it is helpful to know what you're really after.

Comment: Could you add an example that shows what is going on?

Comment: a linebreak in the tex source is the same as a space

Comment: The linebreaks within a paragraph in the source text have no any effect in the PDF, but if this is a problem when edited, there are many tools to fix that, for example [here](http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561390-remove-line-breaks.aspx).

Comment: For me this is a problem if I want to use a grammar checking tool on the source file.

Answer (score 6):

From the LyX wiki:

> If you do not want any line breaks within paragraphs, set
>   Tools→Preferences→Output→General→Output line length to 0.

https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ImportExport